# Keep only first cluster of non-nan values in Pandas data frame row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F
 0    1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 1    2     5     6     1    NaN    1
 2    2     3    NaN    1     4     1
 3    5     5     2     1     2     1
 4   NaN    2     3     4     1     2
 5   NaN   NaN    2    NaN   NaN    1
```

How do I only keep the first grouping of non NaN values such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F
 0    1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 1    2     5     6     1    NaN   NaN
 2    2     3    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 3    5     5     2     1     2     1
 4   NaN    2     3     4     1     2
 5   NaN   NaN    2    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Eliminating any values after a NaN value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create a mask. It's a little hard to explain so I'll step through slowly

```
m = (df.notnull().cummax(1) & df.isnull()).cummax(1)
df.mask(m)
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  6.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  5.0  5.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
4  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0  1.0  2.0
5  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

#### Explanation

```
# Row-wise True filling after/including first non-null value.
df.notnull().cummax(1)
       A      B     C     D     E     F
0   True   True  True  True  True  True
1   True   True  True  True  True  True
2   True   True  True  True  True  True
3   True   True  True  True  True  True
4  False   True  True  True  True  True
5  False  False  True  True  True  True

# Adding the `&` condition ensures first True value for each row is after the first 
# non-null group
df.notnull().cummax(1) & df.isnull()
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False   True   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False   True  False
2  False  False   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False   True   True  False

# We now turn everything to True after the first, row-wise
(df.notnull().cummax(1) & df.isnull()).cummax(1)
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False   True   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False   True   True
2  False  False   True   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the same logic as Alollz, using `cumsum` with `mask` , the first mask is to control the leading `NaN`, the where is mask the False to NaN

```
s=df.isna().cumsum(1).mask(df.isna()).bfill(1)
df.where(s.eq(s.min(1),axis=0))
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  6.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  5.0  5.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
4  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0  1.0  2.0
5  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I can't keep up with the name changes (-:

Comment: @piRSquared haha sir , This will be the last time~

Comment: Bah, this question made my head hurt. Nice answer :D